# How to update page after fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am creating a simple chat room and am expecting the page to update when I enter a message into a text box and press enter.

The room is receiving messages from a URL, but I have to reload the page to see my new message whenever I post it.

How do I display these messages without having to reload the page?

fetch GET:

```
fetch('https://curriculum-api.codesmith.io/messages', { 'method': 'GET' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => addText(data))
```

fetch POST:

```
  textBox.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
      const func = async function postReply() {
        const currentDate = new Date()
        const message = textBox.value;
        textBox.value = ''
        return await fetch('https://curriculum-api.codesmith.io/messages',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              'message': message,
              'created_at': currentDate.toUTCString(),
              'created_by': 'Nate & Dewey'
            })
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          // .then(json => addText(json.message))
      }
      func()
      // $('#result').load('https://curriculum-api.codesmith.io/messages');
    }
  })
```

addText() function (used by GET)

```
  function addText(data) {
    let messageNum = 0
    let current = data[messageNum]
    while (current) {
      const text = document.createElement('div');
      border.appendChild(text);
      text.innerText = current.message + ' (' + current.created_by + ')'
      messageNum++
      current = data[messageNum]
    }
  }
```

Comment: uncomment `// .then(json => addText(json.message))`

Comment: when I uncomment that and test it it returns a TypeError; can not read properties of undefined